# Passing angled bracket in hex via JSON AJAX from PHP to JS

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, ajax, json

My system runs some MySQL queries in PHP to retrieve data. The data that is retrieved is structured in an array similar to below:

```
$ret = array(
    "name" => "John Doe",
    "location" => "Antarctica",
    "description" => "Height < 200"
);
```

I return this through AJAX via:

```
echo json_encode($ret);
```

The AJAX error event is fired and upon inspection of the returned data (jqXHR.responseText) via Chrome console,  I'm noticing:

```
"description" : "Height \x3c 200"
```

which is throwing a parse error.

I know that \x3c is the hex representation of "<" and apparently, that form renders the JSON invalid. I can't seem to find a way to make it such that I'm able to pass the angled bracket via JSON in a valid form. Direct string replace of "\x3c" on the PHP side doesn't work.

Further, I know that specifying the AJAX return as HTML will work, but I'm passing a set of data hence the use of JSON.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
echo json_encode( $ret, JSON_HEX_TAG );
```

Use `json_last_error()` to debug.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Answer (score 1):

Using the native Chrome JSON object (window.JSON), i am able to parse the output from you php program no problem,

```
"description" : "Height \x3c 200"
```

and am able to serialize that into a javascript JSON object.

```
var jsonString = JSON.stringify({"description": "Height \x3c 200"});
//jsonString has the value "{"description":"Height < 200"}"

var jsonObject = JSON.parse(jsonString);
//jsonObject has an object that looks like this 
//Object
//description: "Height < 200"
//__proto__: Object
```

if you need compatibility with browsers that don't support a native JSON object, i would recommend using a library such as JQuery.

Additionally, the json_encode() function in PHP can be passed a configuration object to customize exactly how your JSON is encoded, if you don't like the '\x3c', you can change it to something your javascript parser may like better like '≶' :)

http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

Comment: I'm using a third-party JS control so I don't have the opportunity to manipulate the AJAX-returned data via methods like JSON.stringify(). However, the json_encode() modifiers work like a charm :)